# Xerces, external schema and default namespace

Tags: java, xerces

I have a XSD file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="someNameSpace"
    xmlns="someNameSpace"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
...
</xs:schema>
```

In Java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking", true);
dbf.setAttribute("http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-schemaLocation", "someNameSpace file:///home/.../schema.xsd");

DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setErrorHandler(new SomeHandlerImpl());
Document doc = builder.parse(input);
```

Input is a file starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projekt xmlns="someNameSpace">
```

If I remove namsepaces and use `http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-noNamespaceSchemaLocation` property instead `http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-schemaLocation`, it works. But with namespaces I've absolutely no idea, what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. The schema should start like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://some/namespace/identifier"
    xmlns="http://some/namespace/identifier"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

And root start tag is defined this way:

```
<rootElement xmlns="http://some/namespace/identifier"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://some/namespace/identifier whatever.xsd">
```

Finally I updated my code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
SchemaFactory scf = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
URL schemaUrl = getClass().getResource(SCHEMAFILE);

dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setSchema(schema);

DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setErrorHandler(errHandler);
Document doc = builder.parse(input);
```